# Reading and recording character ASCII values to vector

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to open a text file, read the the file character by character, and store the ascii value of each character to a vector.

I am successful in opening and reading the file, but I am confused as to why the integer values are not being stored in my vector. All the values are being stored as 0s.

Sounds silly, but I wasn't sure if casting the char c to an integer was the issue, so I stored the (int) c value to a variable i before inputting it into the vector. The problem is, I know i is storing the ASCII values as intended, but I couldn't figure out why these values weren't being transferred to the vector.

```
    char c;
    std::vector<int> ascii;

    while( inFile.get(c) )
    {
        std::cout << c;
        ascii.push_back( (int) c );
    }

    inFile.close();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(auto& i : ascii)
    {
        std::cout << ascii[i] << " ";
    }
```

odoylerules

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using range-for loop, so `i` is integer from vector, it is not index of vector:

```
for(auto& i : ascii)
    {
        std::cout << ascii[i] << " ";
    }
```

should be

```
for(auto& i : ascii)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
```